# Redefinition of type in different libraries

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I get `byte redefinition` error when I try to compile my application. One is defined in `Crypto++` library and the other one in `rpcdnr.h` of Windows Kit. I tried many things but none worked. Any idea to solve the problem is appreciated.

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

Thanks

P.S. I'm using Qt on Windows.

Comment: instead of byte, try with different name

Comment: Don't spam tags, do you mean C or C++?

Comment: Have you included one header more than once without using `inclusion guards` in your code?

Comment: @Rajeshkumar I can't edit library or Windows SDK headers. Even if I do, I get compile error on the edited file headers.

Comment: Is the one in the Cryptp++ library inside a namespace and if so are you using `using namespace whatever_it_i;`?

Comment: @Raindrop7 well all headers has #ifdef that prevents compiler to read twice. The problem is same `byte` is defined in different libraries

Comment: @NathanOliver yes I use `using namespace CryptoPP`.

Comment: @MustafaChelik put your declaration in a namespace, and remove  `using namespace`

Comment: So I guess you can use namespaces.

Comment: @MustafaChelik Get rid of it then.  If the namespace name is long you can [alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias) it to save some typing

Comment: @MustafaChelik don't use `using namespace CryptoPP;  ... SomeCryptoFunction(...)` but just `CryptoPP::SomeCryptoFunction(...)`.

Comment: I removed the `using`, now I get many undefined type errors. Now I have to put `CryptoPP::` before every type, right?

Comment: @MustafaChelik yes, before every CryptoPP type and also before every CryptoPP function and possibly other CryptoPP stuff

Comment: @MustafaChelik you can do `using CroptoPP::SomeType` so that type don't need the qualification.

Comment: thank you so much guys. appreciate your help +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces were created for this reason so to avoid interference between identifiers define them under a namspace:

```
namespace crypto{
    typedef unsigned char byte;
};

namespace rpcndr{
    typedef unsigned char byte;
};


int main(){
    crypto::byte  bValue = 7;
    rpcndr::byte  bvalue2 = 10;

    ret
}
```